# How do I pass an entire array pointer as const such that the values cannot be changed? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

How do I pass an entire array pointer as const such that the values cannot be changed? I am passing in an array to a function like this:

```
double myArr[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
double* pArr = myArr;

double myVal = MyFunc(pArr, 5);
```

MyFunc's header right now is:

```
MyFunc(double* pArr, int length)
```

I want to make sure that the function cannot modify the values inside the array at all.

How do I do this?

Comment: You need not pArr here. double myVal = MyFunc(myArr, 5); works as well

Comment: Interesting, the disparity in the answers regarding `double const *` versus `const double *`. They have the exact same meaning to the compiler, so there is no right answer. Whether the `const` precedes or follows `double` is pure human preference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your function signature to:

```
MyFunc(double const* pArr, int length);
```

Note that this is equivalent to:

```
MyFunc(const double* pArr, int length)
```

Which one you prefer is a matter of pure taste (I prefer the first, as I find it more readable -- it's the items in `pArr` that are const, not the pointer itself).

Comment: pointer constant is equivalent to constant pointer? i always thought there was a difference- pointer const is where pointer points to the same location in memory throughout and can be used to change the memory contents while const pointer is where pointer can change and point to a diff memory location but can't change the underlying val of the memory? correct me if im wrong...

Comment: Also the first version behaves as expected when typedefs start to be applied to the types. This it makes things more consistent.  But another one for the style gods.

Comment: @Dhruv Gairola: It depnds were the const is. const always binds to the left (unless it is the left most element then it binds to the right).  `double const*` and `double * const` are different.

Comment: @Dhruv Gairola: The pointer itself can be changed (i.e. is not const) unless there is a `const` *after* the `*`. So `const T* p` and `T const* p` are both pointers to constant objects, while `T * const p` is a constant pointer to a mutable object, and `T const* const p` is a constant pointer to a constant object.

Answer (score 3):

Just make MyFunc take `(const double *pArr, int length)` for its arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass it by const pointer,

```
MyFunc(const double* const pArr, int length); // pArr or content of pArr will not change
```

If you have liberty to pass `myArr` then pass it by reference:

```
MyFunc(const double (&arr)[length]); // where length is known at compile time
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the argment as const pointer.  The function signature will look like this:

`double MyFunc(const double* arr, size_t count);`

Answer (score 2):

> How do I pass an entire array pointer as const?

Just do it!

```
MyFunc(const double* pArr, int length)
```